# Changing Switch Preference Color

Tags: android

I have settings xml file where i have checkboxpreferences and a switchpreference , when i switch to dark mode , the tint of the switch and checkbox don't automatically change according to the selected mode
here is an image of what i'm talking

[image]

So the switchpreference is supposed to be white when app is in dark mode but it is not changing , can anyone help me to fix it , thank you

*This is my setting xml file

```
<androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Preference
        android:title="@string/YourPreferredLanguage"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_language_24"/>

        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:title="@string/French"
            android:key="french"
            />
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:title="@string/English"
            android:key="english"
            />
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:title="@string/spanish"
            android:key="spanish"
            />
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:title="@string/Portuguese"
            android:key="portuguese"
            />


    <Preference
        android:key="preferences"
        android:title="@string/rateourapp"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_stars_24"/>
        <taki.food.foodappv.RatingPreferences
            android:defaultValue=""
            android:key="customlayout"/>

    <Preference
        android:title="@string/switchmodes"
        app:allowDividerAbove="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_perm_data_setting_24"/>
        <SwitchPreference
            android:key="switchmode"
            android:title="Light Mode ON"/>

</androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: was `ic_baseline_language_24` in some other  color before dark mode?

Comment: No  , i didn't set any color to it before dark mode and it shows black in light mode , what i noticed is that when you don't specify a color , system will automatically show either white in dark mode or black in light mode , as you see with other strings , but for those , i don't know why they didnt change , like checkboxprferences nd switchpreferences

Comment: open `ic_baseline_language_24` see it's `fillColor` attribute set that color you your color accent in colors.xml

Comment: the language icon is working fine and switches color accordinly , the issue is only wth the checkboxpreference and switchpreference because the system generates them automatically , if i could change them , i could have solved the issue , they should be accessed someonhow within the system

Comment: checkboxpreferece and switchpreferece etc gets color accent from your color.xml, is the `fillColor` of languge icon and color accent is same?

Comment: changing the color accent fixed it mate , thank you , if you want to post an answer i ll vote it and mark it correct

Comment: so as a conclusion the coloraccent is the one responsible for changing icons color , what about text or strings mate , colorprimary is the one responsible for text colors ?

Comment: that is why is my second comment i was saying to make same the  fillColor of drawble and color accent , because drawble was doing correct thing so i could infer that it has the color which should also be color accent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `colorAccent` in `colors.xml/styles.xml` defines the color of checkboxes/rating bar ,progressbar/switch and for many other sdk widgets like some color is datePicker.
`colorPrimary` sets the color for Action Bar `colorPrimaryDark` sets the color for status bar they show up in many other places too i don't remember right now but you will notice with time.

also evidently the text color is not set by `colorPrimary` because by default the text is gray and your `colorPrimary` is not gray, the text color comes from an app theme attribute
called `textColor`which is used by the `TextView` internally you can override it in the app theme open the `styles.xml` in the style named `AppTheme` include
`<item name="android:textColor">your color</item>` to change the text color in the whole app

there are many other things you can override from the parent theme by default android studio just overrides `colorAccent` `colorPrimary` and `colorPrimaryDark`you can for example override `windowBackground` incude
`<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/windowBackground</item>` in `AppTheme` to change the background which is by default `white` for all apps there is much more stuff to customize for example overriding the default elevation for dialogs, or default text size or font etc.

so change the default color for `switch` and `ratingbar` you need to override `colorAccent` if that color comes from the color.xml of `values-night` and is also in `values` folder's colors.xml the android chooses the correct one according the the current mode.

**Have a good day**

**Love from india**

Comment: i'll appreciate if you read some of my other answers and  upvote  may be you'll find solutions to your future problems

Comment: That's my pleasure mate for sure , i ll check out them , thank you for the help  , i also got stuck in some other problem , i spent like 4 days trying to solve it but not yet , because im still new to dark mode and i m not much familiar with it , if i open another topic about it , i will let you know and your help is deeply appreciated , good luck and have a good day

Comment: anytime brother , but before asking new question i will recommend reading few articles about dark mode (there are many medium articles and on other blogs)  it is very easy i am quite sure you will not need to ask any question

Comment: Thank you so much mate ,  i'll go for it and read some articles, appreciated

Comment: good, also i don't recommend upvoting all my answers just read ones which are in your scope and only upvote if you find helpful otherwise the system detects it as fake upvoting from a friend.

Comment: i know how it works mate , i dont want to make it sound fake , i ll check your answers from time to time  , if i find something i need and it works for me , i ll upvote it , thank you

Comment: After trying hard , i couldn't fix it , mate if you have time and want to take look , here is my issue i talked about last time , i spent 4 days changing colors and everything but nothing seems to help thank you , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62711416/toolbar-titletextcolor-not-changing-in-dark-mode